# NextJS: Use same component in multiple routes for multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

In my NextJS app, I have a search bar component `OrderSearchBar.js` and I want to use it in both `index.js` and `/purchases.js` pages but with different endpoints.For example,if I click search button on the `index.js` page,it should post form content to /orders and on the `/purchases.js`, form content should post to /purchaseDetails.Is there any way to accomplish this?

[image: File Structure]

OrderSearchBar.js

```
class OrderSearchBar extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeInput = this.onChangeInput.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        nature: '',
        type: '',
        searchBy: '',
        startDate: '',
        endDate: '',
        keyword: ''
    }
}

onChangeInput(e) {

    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const t = {
        nature: this.state.nature,
        type: this.state.type,
        searchBy: this.state.searchBy,
        startDate: this.state.startDate,
        endDate: this.state.endDate,
        keyword: this.state.keyword
    }
    axios.post('/search', t)..then(res => console.log(res.data));
    /*I can do this for single endpoint.but how do I add multiple endpoints 
    for use in different pages?*/


    this.setState({
        nature: '',
        type: '',
        searchBy: '',
        startDate: '',
        endDate: '',
        keyword: ''         
    });
}
```

Comment: pass endpoint uri to this component as props?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can differentiate the current location in your orderSearchBar.js
by getting the pathname of window.location object.

```js
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const t = {
        nature: this.state.nature,
        type: this.state.type,
        searchBy: this.state.searchBy,
        startDate: this.state.startDate,
        endDate: this.state.endDate,
        keyword: this.state.keyword
    }
    const pathName = window && window.location.pathname;
    const destination = (pathName === '/purchases') ? '/purchaseDetails' : '/orders'
    axios.post(destination, t)..then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({
        nature: '',
        type: '',
        searchBy: '',
        startDate: '',
        endDate: '',
        keyword: ''         
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you could use `window` property, this might not work if you're using Nuxt.js or other server side rendering, since the `window` object is not present.

Instead, I suggest you pass a prop down to your component, say:

```
<component :type="'isPurchaseDetails'">
```

or for purchases

```
<component :type="'isPurchases'">
```